# What's the difference between Meta Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, meta

What is the difference between Meta Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow?

I use Stack Overflow often now, but I don't really know if Meta Stack Overflow would be better for me.

Comment: Stack Exchange team has put in considerable effort in writing the Help Center, please go through it. [What is "meta"? How does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: Thanks , i will check that!
Sorry for not reading that first.

Comment: Basic though this question may be, it is surely focused.  BoltClock's answer addresses it nicely.

Comment: I think this question can't be generally wrong when the answer has 20 points as useful. So it means that many people have the same question, including me, and if @StenPelzer hadn't askes, I would have not seen the also the answer from Aziz and BoltClock

Answer (score 20):

Stack Overflow is a site about programming problems.

Meta Stack Overflow is a site about stuff that happens on said site about programming problems.

Assuming you have read [about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about), asking if it's "better for" you is the wrong question. It just doesn't work that way, unless you aren't interested in participating in the community other than to discuss participating in the community (and discussing discussions about participating in the community).